# Errors downloading R package for "Efficient R Programming" by Gillespie and Lovelace

Tags: r

the above-referenced book has an associated R package hosted on github containing datasets and functions used in the book.

The book states this code is used to install the package:
`devtools::install_github("csgillespie/efficient", build_vignettes = TRUE, dependencies = TRUE)`

I receive the following message and errors when running the code:

> SUMMARY: processing the following file failed:
> 'solutions07.Rmd'
> Error: Vignette re-building failed.
> Execution halted Error: Failed to install 'efficient' from GitHub:
> System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed, exit status: 1, stdout & stderr were printed

Do you have any insight into whether the package itself is causing the error versus a local issue on my end? Or how I might figure out the cause and fix for this issue? I appreciate any help you can provide.

This URL provides the section in the online book I am referring to.
https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/introduction.html#book-resources

Comment: perhaps fork it and then try to build it on your machine?

Comment: Installed fine on my Ubuntu 18.04/R 4.1.2 machine. Maybe you need to update your version of R and its toolchain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I run the following code it works:

```
devtools::install_github("csgillespie/efficient", build_vignettes = TRUE, dependencies = TRUE)

devtools::install_github("csgillespie/efficientR")
```

I would suggest to reinstall the `devtools` package using the following code:

```
remove.packages("devtools")

install.packages("devtools", dependencies = TRUE)

library(devtools)
```

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same problem. But after installing Rtools for windows: https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools42/rtools.html

And installing *from source* packages that were recommended to update:
[recommended packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThwrR.png)

Was able to succefully use **efficient**, and access its vignettes.

- Using version R-4.2.1
- devtools version 2.4.5